# How to create a Manipulate Object with an extra field that depends on what is selected in earlier fields?

Tags: manipulate, interactive, lighting, graphics3d

I am interested in exploring the new MaterialShading function.
I have created a Manipulate object with two fields for making a Graphics3d object of ExampleData's built-in cases.
The first parameter relates to the material the object is made of, and the second relates to which object in ExampleData["Geometry3D"] is displayed.
I would like to somehow introduce a third field if the user selects Plastic or Glazed for color.
I have used the following resources:

- [Advanced Manipulate Functionality](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html)
- [Manipulate Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html?q=Manipulate)
- [Materials from Wolfram University Study Group Creating Custom User Interfaces](https://amoeba.wolfram.com/index.php/s/eaEMsFJFLMiGWa3)

A generalization of this question:

- Given a function that accepts n number of arguments f[e1,e2,e3,...en]
- where not all arguments are required
- and the last argument is only applicable to certain inputs for the first inputs
- how to create a Manipulate object that works around this.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{MaterialShading[material], 
   ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", object}, "GraphicsComplex"]}, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint"], {material, {"Aluminum", "Brass", 
   "Bronze", "Copper", "Electrum", "Gold", "Iron", "Pewter", "Silver",
    "Clay", "Foil", "Glazed", "Plastic", "Rubber", "Satin", 
   "Velvet"}}, {object, ExampleData["Geometry3D"][[All, 2]]}]
```

Comment: Please provide a concrete example and the code that you have tried. Explain what specific problems you are having.

Comment: I forgot! I meant to add my code. Please consider un downvoting my question.

Comment: There are 16 materials and 27 objects for a total of 432 combinations. Which of the combinations are known to cause problems and what is the nature of the problem?

Comment: I want to add a field for the color of plastic and glazed materials when those are selected as the materials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

A brute force approach is to just nest two Manipulates.

```
SetOptions[Graphics3D,
  Boxed -> False,
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint"];

Manipulate[
 If[(material === "Plastic" || material === "Glazed"), Manipulate[
   Graphics3D[{
     MaterialShading[{material, color}],
     ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", object}, "GraphicsComplex"]}],
   {color, ColorSlider},
   Paneled -> False],
  Graphics3D[{
    MaterialShading[material],
    ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", object}, "GraphicsComplex"]}]],
 Row[{
   Control[{{material, "Plastic"},
     {"Aluminum", "Brass", "Bronze", "Copper", "Electrum", "Gold", 
      "Iron", "Pewter", "Silver", "Clay", "Foil", "Glazed", "Plastic",
       "Rubber", "Satin", "Velvet"}}],
   Spacer[50],
   Control[{object,
     ExampleData["Geometry3D"][[All, 2]]}]}],
 TrackedSymbols :> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
materials =   {"Aluminum", "Brass", "Bronze", "Copper", "Electrum", "Gold", "Iron",
 "Pewter", "Silver", "Clay", "Foil", "Glazed", "Plastic", "Rubber", "Satin", "Velvet"};

objects = ExampleData["Geometry3D"][[All, 2]];

assoc = Association[# -> ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", #}, "GraphicsComplex"]& /@ objects];
```

We can use a single `Manipulate` with the control `color` added only if `material` is `"Plastic"` or `"Glazed"`:

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{
       MaterialShading[material /. m : "Plastic" | "Glazed" -> {m, color}],
       assoc @ object},
      Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "ThreePoint"],
  Row[{Control[{{material, "Plastic"}, materials }],
       Spacer[50], 
       Dynamic @ If[(material === "Plastic" || material === "Glazed"), 
           Row[{ Control@{{color, Red}, ColorSlider}, Spacer[50]}], 
           Spacer[0]],
       Control[{object, objects}]}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{
       MaterialShading[material /. m : "Plastic" | "Glazed" -> {m, color}],
       assoc @ object}, 
    Boxed -> False,  Lighting -> "ThreePoint"],
Dynamic @ If[material === "Plastic" || material === "Glazed", 
   Row[{Control @ { {material, "Plastic"}, materials }, 
        Control @ {{color, Red}, ColorSlider}, 
        Control @ {object, objects  }}, Spacer[20]], 
   Row[{Control@{ {material, "Plastic"}, materials }, 
        Control @ {object, objects}}, Spacer[20]]]]
```